# Storing array of objects in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

Can anybody provide a solution to this? I am getting an array of objects in req.body . I am looking for a way to store it in MongoDB using Mongoose.

**MySchema**:

```
const hobbySchema = new Schema({

     hobbies:[{ 
         hobby : {type:String}
     }]
},{collection:'hobby'});
```

**req.body**

```
[{ newHobby:'Hobby 1'},{ newHobby:'Hobby 2'},{ newHobby:'Hobby 3'}]
```

**API part**

```
router.post('/hobby',(req,res)=>{
        console.log(req.body);
        let hobby = new Hobby({
               hobbies: [{
                            hobby: req.body.newHobby // I don't know how to store it in mongo
                   }]
        });
        hobby.save((err)=>{
            if(err){
                res.json({ success:false , message:err});
            } else {
                res.json({ success:true , message:'Hobbies saved!'});
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: If it's already an "array" in the body payload of the request then you do not need to wrap the content in an array "again". Simply `new Hobby({ "hobbies": req.body })`. But you really should be doing the POST with a key name instead of directly into the body.

Comment: Of course you need the same properties as your model. So change to `[{ hobby:'Hobby 1'},{ hobby:'Hobby 2'},{ hobby:'Hobby 3'}]` in the actual request. Or use `map()` as in `new Hobby({ hobbies: req.body.map(e => ({ hobby: e.newHobby }) ) })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const Hobby= require('./hobby.model'); 
router.post('/hobby',(req,res)=>{

    Hobby.create({hobbies:req.body},function(err,hobby){

            if(err){
                res.status(4xx).json({ success:false , message:err});
            } else {
                res.status(2xx).json({ success:true ,hobby:hobby message:'Hobbies saved!'});
            }

})
});
```